# How to Handle Transaction which inserts Huge data(15 millions) across multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, transactions, transactionscope

I have long running process. Which inserts huge data(15 million) across multiple database Tables.  It's getting failed after 10 minutes(I kept Transaction time out as 10 minutes). 
I use Sql server as my database.
I am using SqlBulk Inserts for my insertions. Even though it's failing.
How to handles insertions on such Huge Data?